# Mock inner instance on class to test

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, refactoring

I am writing some test cases using Mockito. I am facing a problem, I looked for the solution on the net but I did not find a clear answer.

Given the following classes I want to mock all calls to the method `getMessage`
on the `ClassB` on all instances of this type.

```java
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB b = new ClassB("From ClassA");

    int methodToTest() {
        System.out.println("methodToTest use instqnce ClassB " + b.getMessage());
        return -1;
    }
}

class ClassB {
    private String message;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public ClassB(final String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }

    /**
     * @return the message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * @param message the message to set
     */
    public void setMessage(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

What I tried but it did not work is the following:

```java
public class ClassATest {

    @Test
    public void testOK1() {
       ArgumentCaptor<ClassB> captorClassB = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ClassB.class);
       Mockito.doReturn("MOCK message").when(captorClassB.capture()).getMessage();

       ClassA a = new ClassA();
       assertTrue(a.methodToTest() == -1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOK2() {
        Mockito.doReturn("MOCK message").when(Mockito.any(ClassB.class)).getMessage();

        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        assertTrue(a.methodToTest() == -1);
    }
}
```

My question is firstly whether it is possible. Secondly, how? Shall I refactor the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of creating a new ClassB you should pass a ClassB in the constructor of ClassA. In that way you could pass your mocked ClassB instance and verify that it is called.

```java
public class ClassA { 
    ClassB classB;

    public ClassA(ClassB classB){
        this.classB = classB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see the point. What if the instance of type ClassB is given by another class into the class ClassA : int methodToTest() {b = classC.getB();
    System.out.println("methodToTest use instqnce ClassB " + b.getMessage());
    return -1;
}

Comment: In that case, I would recomend you to pass classC as a parameter (or to the function or to the class), create a new class in the test which inherits from classC and overwrite the method getB to return the ClassB you want.

Comment: `public class ClassATest {
//.... Your tests here....
}

static class ClassCMock extends ClassC {
 
 public ClassB getB(){
  return mockedClassB;
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I made up the following solution. If there are some drawback with this approach please point it out.

```java
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB b = new ClassB("From ClassA");

    int methodToTest() {
        System.out.println("methodToTest use instqnce ClassB " + getClassB().getMessage());
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * 
    */
    public ClassB getClassB() {
        return b;

   }
}



class ClassB {
    private String message;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public ClassB(final String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }

    /**
     * @return the message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * @param message the message to set
     */
    public void setMessage(final String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}


public class ClassATest {

    @Test
    public void testOK() {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();

        ClassB b = new ClassB("MOCK message");

        ClassA spyA = spy(a);

        Mockito.doReturn(b).when(spyA).getClassB();

        assertTrue(spyA.methodToTest() == -1);
    }

}
```